# How to enumerate the path (4,1), (2,2), (2,3), (2,4) using this specific notation for steps on a grid.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

A frog is positioned at the origin of the coordinate plane. From the point $(x, y)$, the frog can jump to any of the points $(x+1, y),(x+2, y),(x, y+1)$, or $(x, y+2)$. Find the number of distinct sequences of jumps in which the frog begins at $(0,0)$ and ends at $(4,4)$.

How do you easily enumerate the distinct sequences for a mixed move such as (4,1), (2,2),(2,3), (2,4) using the notation in if "u" denotes a step up, "2u" denotes a single step going two steps up, "r" denotes a step right, "2r" denotes a single step moving two units right. For example ,
[image]

[image]
If this method is akin to bute force, then how do you relate the pure distinct sequences of steps for example (0,3) =3 and add that up with (0,1) to algebrically derive the number of distinct sequence of steps for (3,1)=10?

Comment: For a boundary condition it seems from $(0,0)$ to either $(n,0)$ or $(0,n)$ can be done in  $F_n$ different ways,  where $F_n$ is the $n$-th Fibonacci number.

Answer (score 0):

You want to compute the double-indexed sequence $a(n,k)$ that satisfies $a(n,k)=a(n-1,k)+a(n-2,k)+a(n,k-1)+a(n,k-2)$.

This sequence can be found in the Fibonacci-Pascal triangle, sequence [A036355](https://oeis.org/A036355) of the OEIS (see also [A036692](https://oeis.org/A036692) for the number of way to go from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$).

A standard way to algebraically derive a closed formula would be to use the recursion formula to derive its generating function $G(x,y)=\frac{1}{1-(1+y)\cdot x-(1+y^2)\cdot x^2}$, which can then be used to compute its coefficient (see e.g. books like Generatingfunctionnology).

Comment: how does those two sequences, match with the distinct paths?

Comment: Is a(n,k) a sum of the element of the sequence?